# A very rude person AND/OR a mix of a mean and rough character

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I know the word in my native language but whenever I translate it, it would be "rude", when there's another word in my language that fits "rude", which is "وقح" in Arabic. The word I want is "فظ".

The story behind it:
A person "X" said several rude and mean sentences to another person "Y". So "Y" got offended and asked "X": Why are you being rude?- But I used rude before, and I don't want to repeat it, besides that it doesn't estimate the situation as it is.

The word I want describes a person that he is more than rude, he is mean and rough at the same time, also unfriendly.

I found "abrupt" and "blunt", but I'm not sure if they fit the description.

Comment: What are the words in your language. That would help us understand your prior research.

Comment: @JamesK -The word I want is "فظ" in Arabic. And for rude, it is "وقح".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying someone is "rude, mean and rough" is very negative and "abrupt" doesn't capture that; it means the person gives short demands, not polite requests. Whereas "blunt" suggests he is too direct, again it doesn't capture the idea of "mean" or "rough".

It may be best just to use your words "mean", and "rough".  If you mean the person fights instead of persuading you could say "aggressive" or "violent".  If you mean that they do or say hurtful things on purpose, you could say "cruel". You might say that a person who is mean and rough to someone weaker is a "bully". Someone who is unpleasant can be called "obnoxious".

> Jonny said several mean and rude things to his sister, so I took him to his room and asked him "why are you being so obnoxious?".
>
> Martha is becoming the work bully. She laid into Bob when he delivered his report into the Shanghai deal, saying all sorts of rude things about the quality of his work. She was really cruel, mocking him for a spelling mistake on page 2.

Comment: Thank you for answering. That person "X" said several rude and mean sentences to another person "Y". So "Y" got offended and asked "X": Why are you being rude?- But I used rude before, and I don't want to repeat it, besides that it doesn't estimate the situation as it is. I will go with (mean and rough) as you have suggested if there is no one single word for them.

Comment: edited based on your comments.

Comment: Well, you could have edited it properly at least, not just copy-paste thing.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comments. I also copied and pasted your comments into your question where you should have them in the first place. When clarifying a question it is always better to make an edit, as comments are intended to be temporary.  I copy pasted, so your question would remain in your words not mine.  My edits to my answer however are not copy pasted from anywhere. I edited to add some more suggestions and two illustrations, in my words, not yours. My edits were very "proper". And you are welcome.

Comment: I was talking about my question's edit, not your answer's one, I didn't notice it actually, but now as you have mentioned it, I will use "obnoxious" since it seems to fit greatly. About the copy-paste thing, you make a good point, but I care more about a proper edit rather than original one. However, it seems that we have different priorities and that's fine. Moreover, don't take it personally, I didn't mean anything but appreciation. Thank you AGAIN.